# Regex for ISO 8601 durations

Tags: regex, dateinterval

I need a regular expression to validate durations in the [ISO 8601 duration format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) (with the exception of fractional parts which I don't need).

> PnYnMnDTnHnMnS
>
> PnW

Here is what I have:

```
^P(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+W)?(\d+D)?(T(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?)?$
```

The only problem is that the strings `P` and `PT` are allowed with this regex as all of the parts are "zero or one" `?`.

- There needs to be at least one component (date or time)
- If there is a `T` then there needs to be a time component (H, M, or S)
- If there is a `T` then there may or may not be any date components (Y, M, or D)
- Overflow is allowed (e.g. `P72H` is mostly equivalent to `P3D`)

Acceptable inputs:

```
P1Y        // date component only
P2MT30M    // date and time components
PT6H       // time component only
P5W        // another date component
```

Unacceptable inputs:

```
P         // no components
PT        // no components
P3MT      // T specified but not time components
```

Right now the invalid strings are passing client-side validation but failing on the server-side because it's passed into [`DateInteval`](https://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php) but I'd like to fail on the client side if possible. If everyone was using Chrome 40+ I could specify `minlength='3'` on the input element to help but that isn't the case unfortunately.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you have almost all parts optional, but you want to make sure there is something else after `P` or `T`, you can make use of look-aheads:

```
^P(?=\d+[YMWD])(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+W)?(\d+D)?(T(?=\d+[HMS])(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?)?$
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

They require a sequence of digits followed by a letter from the specified set to appear right after the preceding pattern.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV0fP9/4)

**UPDATE**

If `P` can be "empty", use

```
^P(?!$)(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+W)?(\d+D)?(T(?=\d+[HMS])(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?)?$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bV0fP9/5). Here, `(?!$)` makes sure the string is not equal to `P`, and there must be some other symbols on the right.

Or, as @UlugbekUmirov suggests, it is [enough to just use `T(?=\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/bV0fP9/6) (since all the optional parts start with a digit):

```
^P(?!$)(\d+Y)?(\d+M)?(\d+W)?(\d+D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+H)?(\d+M)?(\d+S)?)?$
```

**UPDATE 2**

If the numbers can be both float or integers, add `(?:\.\d+)?` after each `\d+`. Here is an updated pattern from Update 1:

```
^P(?!$)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?W)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?S)?)?$
```

Answer (score 5):

The answers above don't include the situation of a decimal fraction (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) for details). The decimal fraction can occur on the last element. The following regex includes decimal fraction:

```
^P(?!$)((\d+Y)|(\d+\.\d+Y$))?((\d+M)|(\d+\.\d+M$))?((\d+W)|(\d+\.\d+W$))?((\d+D)|(\d+\.\d+D$))?(T(?=\d)((\d+H)|(\d+\.\d+H$))?((\d+M)|(\d+\.\d+M$))?(\d+(\.\d+)?S)?)??$
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/RltxfI/1) for tests.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this message](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/9q0ftb37dv7.fsf%40gmx.us) about [ISO 8601-2:2019(en)](https://www.iso.org/standard/70908.html), a negative duration is expressed with a minus `-` sign before the `P` and it also seems that an explicit positive duration can be indicated with a plus `+` sign.

Useful to include `[-+]?` or `(-|\+)?` before `P`

Finally, That message also shows the following examples from ISO 8601-2:2019(en) indicating that each component of the duration can be negatively signed.

```
| EXAMPLE 7 '-P2M1D' is equivalent to 'P-2M-1D'.
| EXAMPLE 8 '-P5DT10H' is equivalent to 'P-5DT-10H'.
```

Adding `[-+]?` before digits in components and allowing `-+` in the lookahead for `T` makes sense to be 8601-2 compliant

`^[-+]?P(?!$)(([-+]?\d+Y)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+Y$))?(([-+]?\d+M)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+M$))?(([-+]?\d+W)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+W$))?(([-+]?\d+D)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+D$))?(T(?=[\d+-])(([-+]?\d+H)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+H$))?(([-+]?\d+M)|([-+]?\d+\.\d+M$))?([-+]?\d+(\.\d+)?S)?)??$`

Answer (score 0):

Answers above require additional post-processing.
 `/^(-?)P(?=\d|T\d)(?:(\d+)Y)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+)([DW]))?(?:T(?:(\d+)H)?(?:(\d+)M)?(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)S)?)?$/`
An output:

```
["P2Y9M3DT12H31M8.001S", "", "2", "9", "3", "D", "12", "31", "8.001", index: 0, input: "P2Y9M3DT12H31M8.001S", groups: undefined]
```

Comment: supports fractional part in seconds only

Answer (score 0):

If you are searching for a regular expression containing a start date ***and*** duration, check this out:

```
^(\d{4}(-\d{2}(-\d{2})?(?!:))?(T\d{2}(:\d{2}(:\d{2})?(\.\d+)?)?)?(Z|([+,-]\d{2}(:\d{2})?))?)?P(([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?Y)?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?M)?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?D)?T?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?H)?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?M)?([0-9]+([.,][0-9]*)?S)?)|\d{4}-?(0[1-9]|11|12)-?(?:[0-2]\d|30|31)T((?:[0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):?(?:[0-5][0-9]):?(?:[0-5][0-9]|60)|2400|24:00)$
```