# Validating ISO 8601 Duration string with fractions

Tags: regex

This might be a bit of a tricky one, I'm trying to come up with a regular expression to validate various given date intervals against the 8601 spec (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations).  I have pretty much else all the cases working with the following regular expression:

`^P(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?D)?(?:T(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?S)?)?$`

However the one place it falls down is in the aspect of the fractional unit only being allowed on the smallest supplied unit.

So for example:

P1DT1.5H is a valid string (The above regex technically allows this)
P1.5DT1H is not a valid duration, as the hours are the smallest supplied unit.
P1.5DT1.5H would also not be valid.

I've reached the end of my regex skills to try and figure out a way to incorporate this into the above.  Anyone have any help or guidance on how this might be achived?

Comment: Can we assume the fractional part can only appear if there are no more digits to the right? Try `^P(?!.*\d\.\d.*\d)(?!$)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?W)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+(?:\.\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:\.\d+)?S)?)?$`. See https://regex101.com/r/pv3922/2

Comment: That did the trick.  I modified it a little so commas can also be used as the decimal symbol.  But that's awesome thanks a lot.

So the final version ended up looking like:
`^P(?!.*\d[,.]\d.*\d)(?!$)(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?W)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?S)?)?$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the fractional part can only appear if there are no more digits to the right, you can use

```
^P(?!.*\d[,.]\d.*\d)(?!$)(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?Y)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?W)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?D)?(T(?=\d)(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?H)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?M)?(\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?S)?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pv3922/3).

The `(?!.*\d[,.]\d.*\d)` negative lookahead fails the match if there is a number with a fractional part followed with another number anywhere in the string.

You can learn more about the pattern used here in the [Regex for ISO 8601 durations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32045167/3832970) post.